# Correct while loop output (Java)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I need to now make my program output this:

Enter a word: house
What letter do you want to replace?: a
There is no a in house.
What letter do you want to replace?: b
There is no a in house.
What letter do you want to replace?: e
With what letter do you wish to replace it? w
The new word is housw.
_____________________________________.

Here is my current output:

Enter a word: house
What letter do you want to replace?: a
There is no a in house
What letter do you want to replace?: b
With what letter do you wish to replace it?

_____________________________________.

I am having trouble with my while loop.And im not sure how to correct the error. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WordScrambler {

    //name

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String word = "";
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a word: " + word);
        word = keyboard.nextLine();


        String readChar = null;
        System.out.print("What letter do you want to replace?: ");
        readChar = keyboard.next();

        while(true)
        {
            if(word.contains(readChar))
            {
                String changeChar;
                System.out.print("With what letter do you wish to replace it? ");
                changeChar = keyboard.next();

                System.out.println(word.replace(readChar, changeChar));

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("There is no "+ readChar + " in " + word);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("What letter do you want to replace?: ");
                readChar = keyboard.next();
                String changeChar;
                System.out.print("With what letter do you wish to replace it? ");
                changeChar = keyboard.next();
                System.out.println(word.replace(readChar, changeChar));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We're not doing your homework for you. Ask a proper question.

Comment: what error are you getting.Please ask a specific question

Comment: This is not a problem with while loops. Can you title your question something relevant?

Comment: Look at your **else** clause (the letter is not found).  Notice the print statement saying "With what letter do you wish...".  Explain why you are surprised to see this when the letter is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in your

`else` part, you can clearly see that you ask the user with what letter he wishes to replace the original letter, instead of simply saying that the word doesn't contain the letter.

You can fix this by simply removing the two "question" parts out of your else statement.

Parts to remove:

```
    System.out.print("What letter do you want to replace?: ");
    readChar = keyboard.next();
    String changeChar;
    System.out.print("With what letter do you wish to replace it? ");
    changeChar = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println(word.replace(readChar, changeChar));
```

Comment: when I remove this part in my code, the "there is no a in house" turns into a never ending loop. @Code0

Comment: Yes, since you never ask for another input again (scanner.next() blocks the main thread from executing if it's run on the main thread). Simply request a new input and you're set. @Alex

Answer (score 1):

In your else statement once a person enters a character that doesnt exist you tell them that and make them select a new character, but then you do not even check if this new character exists in the string and instead straight away ask them with what character you would like to replace it with. 
Your else statement should look like:

```
    else{
        System.out.print("There is no "+ readChar + " in " + word);
        System.out.print("What letter do you want to replace?: ");
        readChar = keyboard.next();
    }
```

This means your loop will run again and verify if the letter exists.

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in the sequence of statements in your else block. If you have a debugger try debugging your example (go step by step through your program - you will see the problem). If you don't have a debugger try changing the text your system.out.println() is displaying. Just add a bit of unique text to every system.out.println() statement so that they become distinguishable for you. The problem is not far away...

Good luck!